# Setting the ToggleButton on/off text to nothing

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to use this code:

```
actionToggleButton=new ToggleButton(context);
actionToggleButton.setTextOn(null);
actionToggleButton.setTextOff(null);
```

But I'm still getting the default text! How can I clear it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton(this);
    button.setText(null);
    button.setTextOn(null);
    button.setTextOff(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this in XML via the `textOn` and `textOff` attributes:

```
    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle_filter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOn="@null"
        android:textOff="@null"/>
```